# Extracting values from two data frames based on a the same ID column

Tags: r

I want to create a data fame from values in two different data frame
containing same values in column ID

## Input data

```
df1<- data.frame(ID = c(102, 205, 333, 434, 512), Order1 = c("ball", 
"ball", "pen", "glass", "scale"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(102, 205, 333, 434, 512), ActOrder1 = c("cap", 
"watch", "cup", "pen", "pencil"), ActOrder2 = c("cap", "fan", "phone", 
"NA",  "NA"))
```

for all the values of ball in the column Order1 of df1, I want to extract the values in the column ActOrder1 & Actorder2 from df2

## Output

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(102, 205), Order1 = c("ball", "ball"), 
ActOrder1 = c("cap", "watch"), ActOrder2 = c("cap", "fan") )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: I want to extract the values into a new data frame based on a value in column Order1 (ball) of df1.

Comment: Additional the values in the column "Order1" "ActOrder1" and "ActOrder2" do not match. But the corresponding value in the column "ID" matches.

Comment: Since you asked in comments below for more info on left & right joins, the post I flagged this as a duplicate of has 19 answers giving lots of details on different types of joins. Click the link ^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `left_join` with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID') %>%
   filter(Order1 == 'ball')  %>%
   select(names(df1), starts_with('ActOrder'))
```

Comment: Doesnt produce the required output.

Comment: @AashayMehta  if 'df3' is the expected output, the update gives the expected

Comment: Also, what change would I need to make if the df2 had multiple columns and I only wanted to extract values in ActOrder1 and ActOrder2?

Comment: @AashayMehta  Do you still want the 'ID' and 'Order1' columns

Comment: Yes, would still want ID and Order1 column in df3

Comment: @AashayMehta  Please check my `select` statement

Comment: Stay tuned for more questions. Also, any link for left and right join would be appreciated.

Comment: @AashayMehta  If the questions are different, please post as a new one.  Thanks

Comment: @AashayMehta  You can check for vignettes from dplyr https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: GIVES THE FOLLOWING ERROR WITH ACTUAL DATA SET:-  Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: @AashayMehta  Not clear about the error.  Please check your data `str(data)` to see whether the one you showed is similar to that one